# Spring/Mass Systems: Driven Motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem Statement:

A mass *m* is attached to the end of a spring whose constant is *k*. After the mass reaches equilibrium, its support begins to oscillate vertically about a horizontal line *L* according to a formula $h(t)$. The value of *h* represents the distance in feet measured from *L*. Determine the DE of motion if the entire system moves through a medium offering a damping force that is numerically equal to (beta: *B*)(dx/dt).

I understand how to set up the equation and to solve when given numerical values for the above variables. I am stuck however with their solution. They are multiplying h(t) by the spring constant to get the DE:
$$mx''(t) = -kx(t) - Bx'(t) + kh.$$
I thought it would be
$$mx''(t) = -kx(t) - Bx'(t) + h(t)$$
and don't understand why we multiply by the spring constant for the $h(t)$ term.

Can anyone please help me understand this part?

Thank you!

Alex

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Comment: Units, for one thing. Your original idea isn't dimensionally consistent. You're adding Newtons to meters. The only scale in the problem available to multiply $h$ so it has units of $N$ is $m \ddot{x}$ is $k$. So you could easily "fix" your equation even without exactly understanding why $k$ has to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the length of the spring (better difference in length from the rest length) is $(x-h)$. $h$ is not an extra force, but the forced movement of the other end of the spring. So you could better write
$$
m\ddot x + \beta\dot x+k(x-h)=0
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help! This clarifies my confusion :)